# Remove duplicates of specific line keeping only the first appearance of each without touching other unspecified duplicates

Tags: linux, awk, sed, string, duplicate

I'm trying to edit a text file containing several duplicates. The goal is to keep only the first match of a string and remove the rest duplicate lines of the same string.

In the example file

```
* Title 1
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

* Title 1
** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

* Title 2
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

* Title 2
** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src
```

I'd like to keep one of each `* Title N` and *keep all other unrelated/unspecified duplicate lines* on the file.
So the result would be:

```
* Title 1
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

* Title 2
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src
```

The traditional solutions for removing duplicates like

```
uniq file.txt
```

[Useful AWK One-Liners to Keep Handy](https://linoxide.com/useful-awk-one-liners-to-keep-handy/):

```
awk '!a[$0]++' contents.txt
```

[shell - How to delete duplicate lines in a file without sorting it in Unix - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix/32513573#32513573)

```
perl -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' file
```

delete every duplicate indiscriminately.

I tried using variations of these solutions and also GNU `sed` in a loop format like

```
duplicateLines=$(grep -E "^\* .*" file.org | uniq)
  printf '%s\n' "$duplicateLines" | while read -r line; do
  sed "s/$line//g2" file.org
done
```

with no success. I don't mind absolute performance so doing multiple iterations like calling `sed`  inside a loop to remove one specified string at a time is no problem.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

It would be nice to be able to do this inside a shell script but I'm open to alternative solutions like Python, C, Java, etc., just tell me what the function/library name is and I'm searching for it there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trivially modify the awk `!a[$0]++` paradigm to make the incrementing pattern-dependent:

```
awk '!a[$0]; /^\* Title/{a[$0]++}' file
```

Comment: OMG this is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In awk we idiomatically use an array named `seen[]` to distinguish between the first vs subsequent appearance of a string, e.g.:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

would only output the first occurrence of every line.

In your case you only want to use that when the current line starts with `* Title` so that'd be:

```
$ awk '!( /^\* Title/ && seen[$0]++ )' file
* Title 1
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

* Title 2
** Subtitle 01
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src

** Subtitle 02
#+begin_src
  Line 001
  Line 002
#+end_src
```